# Solidworks PDM API uses multiple serial numbers when adding a file to the vault. Should something be changed in my code or in my vault?

Tags: c#, solidworks

Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
ModelDoc2 topAssembly = swApp.ActiveDoc

EdmVault5 vault = new EdmVault5();
if (!vault.IsLoggedIn) vault.LoginAuto("Sandbox_Vault", 0);

PackAndGo packNGo = topAssembly.Extension.GetPackAndGo();
packNGo.IncludeDrawings = true;

IEdmFolder5 CADFolder = vault.RootFolder.AddFolder(0, "CAD");

object partPathList, docStatusList;
bool status = packNGo.GetDocumentSaveToNames(out partPathList, out docStatusList);

foreach (string path in partPathList as string[]) CADFolder.AddFile(0, path);
```

Running this code will successfully add the files to the vault. However, every added file now has a [different serial number for each configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYTII.png) (including the "@" and "default" configurations). When I create a new file directly in the vault, it's set up to have every configuration automatically  [share one serial number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nvvf.png). Why is it different in this scenario? Any way to have these added files mimic regular ones and share one serial number across all configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i cannot comment due to reputation, but i would suggest checking that the data card setup is not folder specific and is being used for the newly created folder you are placing the files in.

Also, i notice you are not passing in any EdmAddFlags into the AddFileMethod - these are the possible options (you can pass multiple):

https://help.solidworks.com/2014/English/api/epdmapi/EPDM.Interop.epdm~EPDM.Interop.epdm.EdmAddFlag.html

```
CADFolder.AddFile(0, path, EdmAddFlag.EdmAdd_KeepExistingSerialNumbers);
```